# How to fix " Error starting userland proxy: listen tcp 0.0.0.0:1433 with docker on windows 10

Tags: sql-server, docker

I can't run MySQL server images on docker (Windows 10 Pro), I'm using next command:

```
docker run -e "ACCEPT_EULA=Y" -e "Tel12345678!" -p 1433:1433 -d microsoft/mssql-server-linux
```

[image]

Comment: https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/1804

Comment: `netcfg -d `--this will clean up all networking devices, and requires a reboot